# How can I store gps coordinates in mysql database?

Tags: java, php, mysql

I currently have an android application with php and mysql, but my problem is that, my code always throws 0.000000 both longitude and latitude when it was passed to php and stored it in mysql.

this was my codes

**

```
class myLocationlistener  implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();
                textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Sample.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Sending Location");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String latitude = textLong.getText().toString();
            String longitude = textLat.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latitude));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longitude));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Echos.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**

and this was for php

**

```
if ($_POST['latitude'] && $_POST['longitude'] != null) {
    $db_connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db($db_name);
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gpslocation(latitude, longitude) VALUES('latitude', 'longitude')");


    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

**

If someone knows something about this, please be kind to answer here, or tell me if I am misleading my question.

Comment: what is the type of field for latitude and longitude?

Comment: latitude is decimal(7, 5) and longitude is decimal(8, 5)

Comment: you're inserting strings into decimal-field (you've forgot $ variable signs for latitude and longitude)

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with your PHP Code.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gpslocation(latitude, longitude) VALUES('$latitude', '$longitude')");
```

Change the above line to have $ sign and see.

Better yet use mysql_execute with prepared statements. See [this](http://teaching-2.cs.uml.edu/MySQLdocs/MySQL_Manual/mysql_execute.html) post